# Tweepy - Error while getting access token : "argument 2 to map() must support iteration"

Tags: python, django, twitter, tweepy

I am using [tweepy](http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/auth_tutorial.html#oauth-authentication) (a python lib for twitter api) to create a twitter app. Below is the django view code where I am creating an OAuthHandler with consumer key,secret and getting request token and saving it in django.messages and redirecting it to the authorization url.

Later during the callback view I am retrieving the request token and creating an OAUthHandler, but I getting this below error on 'auth.get_access_token(v)'

```
TweepError at /twitter/return/

argument 2 to map() must support iteration

Traceback :
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/nzee/Downloads/uday/homepage/../homepage/users/views.py" in tw_return
80.   auth.get_access_token(v)


File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tweepy-1.9-py2.6.egg/tweepy/auth.py" in get_access_token
126.             raise TweepError(e)

Exception Type: TweepError at /twitter/return/ Exception Value:
argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

**Views.py code below**

```
def tw_return(request):
  v = request.GET.get('oauth_verifier')

  key = settings.TWITTER_KEY
  secret = settings.TWITTER_SECRET
  auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(key, secret)

  mess = get_messages(request)

  a=[]
  for m in mess:
    a.append(m)

  auth.set_request_token(a[0],a[1])

  auth.get_access_token(v)

  api = tweepy.API(auth)
  api.update_status('tweepy + oauth1!')
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/')      

def twitter(request):
  key = settings.TWITTER_KEY
  secret = settings.TWITTER_SECRET
  auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(key, secret)
  try:
    redirect_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
  except tweepy.TweepError:
    raise Http404

  messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, auth.request_token.key)
  messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, auth.request_token.secret)
  return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

Comment: where does `get_messages()` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**wrong**: <s>I suspect that you are not receiving an oauth_verifier, so it's value is `None` (i.e., not an iterable)</s>

this question may help: [Tweepy twitter oauth authentication not returning oauth_verifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033789/tweepy-twitter-oauth-authentication-not-returning-oauth-verifier)

Here's an example of an appEngine handler that uses tweepy, maybe it'll help?

https://github.com/sclm/tweepy-examples/blob/master/appengine/oauth_example/handlers.py

### Final Answer:

I think you are not getting the correct request token from get_messages()... the error you are getting occurs if you call `auth.set_request_token()` with `None`. Found this in the issues on github for tweepy https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/25

```
# WRONG CODE
auth.set_request_token(None, None)
```

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/twitter/return/?oauth_token=uOkBeKg20kjQjTUo8HxSxgjDO8wlUonCHPZEpCaPN4&oauth_verifier=z9EM0H0TOB0O6aKnZC5fssuMc1Hc9HPt9XpU5Orxdi Getting this full url with oauth_verfier and its not None

Comment: You can see here it expects verifier as the argument https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/auth.py#L105

Comment: yes... I'm trying to hunt down where the map() function is used

Comment: You were right. 

auth.set_request_token(a[0].message,a[1].message) solved it.  

Thanks a lot @Jiaaro. Really appreciate it :)