# Retrieving twitter verifier code from WP7 WebControl

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7, twitter, tweetsharp

I've been working on a fairly basic twitter application for windows phone, and I've come across a problem during the sign in process. I'm using the tweetsharp api, which I'm having no problems with. I've been following this tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/windows/wp7-integrating-twitter-with-your-app/

The problem is that once the user grants permission to my app, I'm unable to read the verifier code off the WebControl and finish off the authentication process. I don't want to have the user copy the code and paste back into my app, as that hinders the user experience and I've never seen a twitter app on a mobile phone do that. I think I've found the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix itL

Here is the code that parses the AbsoluteUri from the verification page for the verifier code:

```
    // From Hammock.Extensions.StringExtensions.cspublic 
    static IDictionary<string, string> ParseQueryString(string query)
    {    
        // [DC]: This method does not URL decode, and cannot handle decoded input    
        if (query.StartsWith("?")) query = query.Substring(1);    
        if (query.Equals(string.Empty))    
        {        
            return new Dictionary<string, string>();    
        }    
        var parts = query.Split(new[] { '&' });    
        return parts.Select(        
            part => part.Split(new[] { '=' })).ToDictionary(            
                pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1] 
            );
    }
```

And here is the code that calls the parsing method:

```
    // called everytime navigation occurs in the WebControl
    private void browserNavigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri); // for debugging
        MessageBox.Show(Browser.SaveToString()); // for debugging
        if (e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("oauth_verifier"))
        {
            var values = ParseQueryString(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
            string verifier = values["oauth_verifier"];
            Globals.client.GetAccessToken(Globals.requestToken, verifier, processAccessToken);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { Browser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed; });
            MessageBox.Show(verifier); // for debugging
        }
    }
```

Here is the AbsoluteUri of the verifier page: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize

The AbsoluteUri does not contain the verifier code! I believe this is the problem, as the code from the tutorial assumes that the verifier code is whithin the page's AbsoluteUri. I took a look at the html of the page in hopes of parsing through it to retrieve the verifier, but unfortunately twitter hides it. Does anyone have any suggestions or workarounds to solving this problem? If I absolutely need to, I could apply for xauth access but I'm saving that as a last resort. If anyone wants to see the html code just ask and I can try to post it. Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Squeesh

Comment: Take a look on the app settings as per this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/4034990/255654

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked out my app settings and read through some more documentation but I believe my app is not considered a web app (in which the verifier is bypassed). I'm only using the WebControl to allow the user to sign in, and after I get the verifier code I will close the browser and bring my user back to my app.